# Is it a measure, complete measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu $ and $\nu $ be the measures in (X, $\mathcal M$) and $a,b \in R_{+}$ For any A let's define $(a \mu + b \nu)(A) = a \mu(A)+b \nu(A)$

- Is $a \mu + b \nu$ a measure on (X, $\mathcal M$) ?
- $\mu, \nu$ are measures complete. Is $a \mu + b \nu$ a measure complete?

I don't know how to start it..

Comment: Please show us your thoughts on the exercise.

Comment: How to start: with the definition of "measure".

Comment: Ok, so
1) aμ+bν(∅) = 0 because μ(∅) = 0 and ν(∅) = 0
2) $aμ+bν( \bigcup Ai) = aμ( \bigcup Ai) +bν( \bigcup Ai) =a \sum \mu Ai + b \sum \nu Ai  $ so it's ok.

and the second one
$A \in aμ+bν$ aμ+bν(A)=0 and don't know what next

Comment: @StefanHansen (or anyone else:)) is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $a\mu +b\nu$ is complete, we have to show that if $A\subseteq N$ with $N\in\mathcal{M}$ and  $(a\mu + b\nu)(N)=0$, then $A\in\mathcal{M}$.

So let such $A$ and $N$ be given. Since $a,b>0$ we have that
$$
a\mu(N)+b\nu(N)\;\;\Longrightarrow\;\;\mu(N)=\nu(N)=0
$$
and since $\mu$ and $\nu$ are complete measures we have $A\in\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: Your argument showing that $a\mu+b\nu$ is a measure is correct by the way.